# Как подружить PostgreSql и MsSql в приложении на C#?

Tags: c#, postgresql, sql-server

Есть две базы данных, Postgre и MS соответственно. Необходимо в приложении выполнить запрос в базу Postgre, получить данные, использовать эти данные в запросе к Ms, получить данные из Ms. Конечно есть возможность создание временной таблицы и сгенерированным insert запросом или bulkCopy загружать в Ms данные из Postgre, чтобы использовать их в запросе. Но у обоих методов минус в том, что необходимо промежуточные данные хранить в оперативной памяти, что может быть неудобно если речь идет о миллионах строк. Существует ли более правильный и оптимальный метод решения данной проблемы?

Comment: SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)

Comment: Маппинг таблицы postgre через драйвер odbc не работает, просто список колонок всегда пуст. Решения в интернете нет. Есть ли другие решения?